# Running selenium tests using Behat Drupal Extension inside DDEV containers

Tags: selenium, drupal, ddev

Problem: Get [Behat Drupal Extension](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalextension) based testing working inside of ddev containers.  This includes adding a separate selenium container to the existing configuration, being able to run Behat tests, and having the  be able to reference the `web` host container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prerequisites: have a working ddev instance hosting Drupal.  There are [examples already](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extending-commands/#drupal-7-example) to set that up, so I won't repeat that here.

The above task required the following additions:

- **selenium container**: The container running selenium.  I used the chrome standalone version.  Add the following to your .ddev folder:

File: docker-compose.selenium.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  selenium:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.13.0-argon
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - web
```

The last bit is critical; the selenium container **needs** to know about the web container running the drupal instance to connect to it, but as it is a dependency of the web container, you can't use 'links'.  You have to use the aliases approach, using the default network.

- **compose override**: A file overriding the defaults for the web container to link the selenium container to it.

File: docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - selenium
    links:
      - db:db
      - selenium:selenium
```

- **Behat configuration**: The following Behat configuration for `MinkExtension` worked for me:

(modify file behat.yml)

```
default:
  extensions:
    "Behat\\MinkExtension":
      goutte: null
      base_url: 'http://web'
      javascript_session: selenium2
      selenium2:
        browser: "chrome"
        wd_host: http://selenium:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities:
          extra_capabilities:
            idle-timeout: 50
```

`base_url` and `wd_host` entries were critical in getting this to work.

For more information on the last, see step 5 in the [Behat Drupal Extension docs](https://behat-drupal-extension.readthedocs.io/en/stable/localinstall.html):

> Configure your testing environment by creating a file called behat.yml with the following. Be sure that you point the base_url at the web site YOU intend to test. Do not include a trailing slash:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
    Drupal\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      base_url: http://seven.l
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
```

Comment: Thx! With this I managed to setup codeception testing with selenium for a CakePHP App.

Comment: The correct answer is still valid or has it changed in something about how to configure ddev drupal with behat selenium?

Answer (score 1):

A current way to run Behat on Drupal with DDEV is via the [ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome](https://github.com/ddev/ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome)

### Steps

1. Install the addon and restart DDEV

```
ddev get ddev/ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome
ddev restart
```

2. Update `behat.yml` to use the addon.

```yaml
  extensions:
    Drupal\MinkExtension:
      base_url: https://web
      selenium2:
        wd_host: http://selenium-chrome:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities:
          chrome:
            switches:
              - "--ignore-certificate-errors"
              - "--disable-gpu"
              - "--headless"
              - "--no-sandbox"
              - "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
```